# Microsoft Bot Framework - very high response times

Tags: azure, botframework

I have 10 seconds response times through any channel. (WebChat and Facebook)
My endpoint is a PAAS instance located in the western United States.
The WebApp has an S3 size and the response times are constant (even if there is only one conversation).

I have the following questions:
Is there any way to optimize this?
What are the Azure Bot Framework SLAs?

Comment: What've you currently done to optimize it? Have you implemented something like this: http://aihelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/11/Using-Application-Insights-With-Microsoft-Bot-Framework?

Answer (score 0):

As bot framework is a preview product, there is no current SLAs.

Are you using the default state storage? If so, part of the slow down you mentioned is probably related.  We highly recommend implementing your own state service.  There is a [blog article here](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/Saving-State-Azure-Extensions/) discussing the implementations there is also a [repository here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-azure) with samples.  This is probably not 100% of your issue but it is probably at least part of it.

Another thing to keep in mind is where your bot is located in relationship to your WebChat client and what instance of the Bot Connector you are using [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/02/02/Direct-Line-performance-improvements/) may provide more info.  Please see the "Geographic Direct Line endpoints" section.